# How to define a zero element when using discriminated unions in F# Array functions

Tags: arrays, f#, discriminated-union

OK, a question, I would like to use an array of discriminated unions in the Array functions. In the code below, I define a type `ResultVari` that is either `Unknown` or a floating point value. I also define the infix plus operator for the type, which returns a value only if both args are not `Unknown`. This works fine.

```
type ResultVari =
    | Unknown
    | Value of float
    static member (+) (a,b) =   // add two ResultVari's together
        match a,b with
        | Value(av),Value(bv) -> Value(av + bv)  // only has a value if both args do.
        | _ -> Unknown

(* Summation of array of ResultVari, such that if any are unknown then the result is Unknown *)
let example1 = [| Value(4.0); Value(5.5); Value(3.1) |]     // summation should be 12.6
let example2 = [| Value(4.0); Unknown; Value(3.1) |]        // summation should be Unknown

let summation (varArray:ResultVari array) =
    Array.sum (+) varArray       //ERROR this value is not a function and cannot be applied

let summation2 (varArray:ResultVari array) =
    Array.fold (+) (Value(0.0)) varArray       // Works

let sum_example1 = summation2 example1
let sum_example2 = summation2 example2

printfn "%A" sum_example1  // 12.6
printfn "%A" sum_example2  // Unknown
```

Using `summation2` the program works as expected with the sum for `example1` being 12.6 and for `example2` being `Unknown`.

But I don't understand why `summation` doesn't work - the  compiler complains "this value is not a function and cannot be applied". In another attempt (not shown), I also got the error of a missing get_Zero element which I understand -- the sum function has to use some type of a zero definition to start the summation, and using the fold function with my Value(0.0) as the start value like in `summation2` solves that.

So is there a way to define a get_Zero element for a discriminated union, or would I have to use a record type instead for ResultVari? Then I could use Array.sum instead of using Array.fold.

Comment: Aren't you only reinventing `option` types with that `ResultVari` type?

Comment: Not exactly, I would like to distinguish an unset variable from others. But you have a point, maybe a 'None' option could take the place of my Unset union member. As far as F# recommended practice, which choice (mine or yours) would be the canonical one?

Comment: *"I would like to distinguish an unset variable from others"* Isn't that what the `None` case implies?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I think that the value `None` _could_ be used to represent that the variable is unset, but isn't the concept of None that the element is 'missing' or something like a null? While in this setting (perhaps unclear), it is meant to represent a variable that may or may not be set, as during the course of a branch and bound exploration or so. So in that case, would my choice of using Unset be more appropriate than making this an option type and using `None` to mean this value is not yet set (which I agree could be made to work).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a `zero` element to use array.sum - like this:

```
type ResultVari =
    | Unknown
    | Value of float
    static member (+) (a,b) =   // add two ResultVari's together
        match a,b with
        | Value(av),Value(bv) -> Value(av + bv)  // only has a value if both args do.
        | _ -> Unknown
    static member Zero with get() = Value(0.0)
```

Then the code becomes:

```
let summation (varArray:ResultVari array) =
    Array.sum varArray
```

This makes sense because when you sum something you need to start from zero and without the zero member, the compiler doesn't know where to start.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the idea was that a zero element needed to be defined, but I wasn't sure how to do it. I was thinking that it needed to be defined outside of the type's scope like a C++ static operator overload, not as a member of the type. Although I guess I just defined the (+) operator in the type - so I should have thought to do the same with an element value.